# Strip Adobe Reader and Version requirements from PDF before outputting it to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf.js

I am planning on using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) to have PDF context via the browser with Javascript. The problem is that some PDFs, the ones I am using, require Adobe's Reader with a specific Version. pdf.js does does not yet(ever?) support spoofing of these. What I need to know is if there's a way in C# to open the PDF and remove these Reader and Version requirements and how to do it. I was planning on using [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to do other PDF manipulation server-side so an example using this would be most helpful. I plan on serving these as an `ActionResult` from an ajax request via MVC 4, so a `MemoryStream` would be most helpful at the end of this manipulation.

Comment: You would have to open the pdf ( in memory ) then save a copy using which ever process you use to read the pdf within a C# program. You could also just use Acrobat to do this if you have control over the pdf files ( I assume you don't ).

Comment: I understand this part... what I am curious about is what I would have to remove from the 'In Memory' copy to remove the version and reader requirements

Comment: OK - so you don't want to just remove the version number :-). I will remove my answer.

Comment: Please be more specific on why your pdfs require adobe reader in some specific version. I see multiple possible reasons: 1) the PDF themselves contain JavaScript code that tests the version and only in case of some given version activates certain contents 2) the PDF contains XFA forms which the reader first has to translate into pages. If you are not sure, please provide a PDF for inspection.

Comment: The USCIS [N-400](http://www.uscis.gov/portal/site/uscis/menuitem.5af9bb95919f35e66f614176543f6d1a/?vgnextoid=480ccac09aa5d010VgnVCM10000048f3d6a1RCRD&vgnextchannel=db029c7755cb9010VgnVCM10000045f3d6a1RCRD)

Comment: @SerjSagan: If you are talking about e.g. http://www.uscis.gov/files/form/n-400.pdf (did you know that can edit your questions?): That is encrypted and probably uses XFA forms, which will most likely only work with Adobe software. I doubt that you will get that to work with pdf.js .

Comment: FYI, XFA is a proprietary format and has nothing in common with PDF. It's using PDF just as a container (similar like you can insert ZIP file inside MS Word document). Just by "accident" Adobe Reader can understand this format, which is XML based and does not use regular page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDF file `n-400.pdf` uses the [Adobe XML Forms Architecture (XFA)](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html). This means you require a viewer that also supports [XFA](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html) which pdf.js seemingly does not.

Such a PDF normally contains some standard PDF content which indicates that the PDF requires some viewer that supports XFA. In your case the content contains

> If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document.

This actually indicates what a XFA enabled viewer does, it renders some pages based upon information in the XFA XML data and displays it instead of the PDF style page descriptions.

While being defined proprietarily by Adobe, the [PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) describes how XFA data is to be embedded in a PDF document, cf. section 12.7.8 *XFA Forms.*

If you only need those forms in a flattened state, you might want to have a look at [iText Demo: Dynamic XFA forms in PDF](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xfademo/uploadpdf.jsp).

Comment: I will accept your answer, as it answers my question, however see my answer for what I was really looking for...

Comment: @SerjSagan Have you determined whether it is ok in your use case to flatten the XFA content to regular PDF? If it is, you should really look into the flattening feature of the *iText Demo: Dynamic XFA forms in PDF* which demonstrates that feature. The result of that flattening has a good chance of been displayable by pdf.js. If the procedure you mention in your answer works for you, though, that's ok, too.

Answer (score 2):

So in the end `pdf.js` was unable to do what I needed it too, however, what I was able to do was convert the `Xfa/Pdf` to a `C#` object then send the pages as needed via Json to my Javascript for rendering in the `HTML5 Canvas`. The code below takes an xfa-in-a-pdf file and turns it into a C# object with the help of `itextsharp`:

```
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileStream(Statics.PdfUploadLocation + PdfFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

    XfaForm xfaForm = new XfaForm(reader);
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xfaForm.DomDocument.InnerXml);

    string xfaNamespace = @"{http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-template/2.6/}";


    List<XElement> formPages = xDoc.Descendants(xfaNamespace + "subform").Descendants(xfaNamespace + "subform").ToList();
    TotalPages = formPages.Count();


    var fieldIndex = 0;
    RawPdfFields = new List<XfaField>();

    for (int page = 0; page < formPages.Count(); page++)
    {
        RawPdfFields.AddRange(formPages[page].Descendants(xfaNamespace + "field")
                    .Select(x => new XfaField
                    {
                        Page = page,
                        Index = fieldIndex++,
                        Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                        Height = GetUnitFromPossibleString((string)x.Attribute("h")),
                        Width = GetUnitFromPossibleString((string)x.Attribute("w")),
                        XPosition = GetUnitFromPossibleString((string)x.Attribute("x")),
                        YPosition = GetUnitFromPossibleString((string)x.Attribute("y")),
                        Reference = GetReference(x.Descendants(xfaNamespace + "traverse")),
                        AssistSpeak = GetAssistSpeak(x.Descendants(xfaNamespace + "speak"))
                    }).ToList());
    }
```